# Centralizing PHP error logging with syslog

Tags: php, logging, log-files, syslog

I have a PHP application that is running on 20 web servers. It's silly to check every servers' PHP error log. I'm planning to centralize the error logging on one (not a web server, a server just used for monitoring).

PHP does support logging to syslog by doing a simple change "error_log = syslog". Then I will configure syslogd to log to my central server.

Did anybody try this before? Any recommendation? Anything I should be careful of? Would this affect performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I've done this.  It works well, and doesn't have any real gotchas.  Performance isn't an issue unless you're logging so many errors that you *really* want to be fixing some of them anyway, or you're logging to a really remote network location (which is a bad idea for all sorts of reasons).

Comment: The app shouldn't have many errors, it actually runs for days without displaying a single error. And the central log server is on the same network.

Does the central server tell you which machine sent this error?

Comment: Yes, the logs will still display the machine name the log entry was generated on, just like local syslogs.

Answer (score 2):

It will only have a real affect on speed if your PHP is regularly throwing errors, and fixing those will save much more then the CPU taken to deal with them.

Answer (score -3):

You'd better not invent bicycles: just use a simple script that's run by cron and uses the `logger` command to duplicate everything from PHP error_log to syslog, or maybe even to a remote host :)

Comment: 1. php has built in capabilities to log to syslog, so why would you make your setup more complex by having a separate script duplicate the log file? 2. you're doubling the disk space  needed to store php logs now. 3. Syslogd already has the ability to forward syslogs to a remote host so once again no need to have your script do that. Rolling your own script IS re-inventing the wheel (or as you put it inventing bicycles)

Comment: Umm, sure. Thought syslog is implemented as a module which is not always accessible. Should have read the manual before answering :)